# Same character show difference Hex code

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring

```
unichar c1 = 12098;
unichar c2 = 25991;
```

When i print This characters show following values,

```
(unichar) $2 = U+2f42 u'⽂'
(unichar) $3 = U+6587 u'文'
```

Same character but different hex code.I want to I identify similar characters in this kind of different encoding. Like bellow

```
if(c1 == c2){
}
```

Actual situation more complex than this. One set of text are extracted text from pdf file encode using glyph and other one is search text word.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Same character but different hex code.

Not *quite* same character. One is the Chinese word for writing; the other refers to the radical used by many related words. It's like the difference between the letter ‘I’ and the word ‘I’.

The difference is so marginal that Unicode would rather not care about it, but has to for compatibility. The radical U+2F42 has a ‘compatibility decomposition’ to the other form, so you can compare them equal by normalising both strings to Normal Form KD first. In NSString that operation is [decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping).

> I want to identify similar characters

That is potentially a much wider question—would need to see more examples to find out if compatibility normalisation alone would satisfy your needs.

Identifying characters that often look alike is an open-ended task. For example should the otherwise-unrelated Greek ν (nu) and Latin v match? What about number 0 vs letter O?

Unicode TR39 has the concept of [confusables](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr39/#confusables) for characters that are commonly visually similar, which is aimed at security issues but might be of help. There is nothing built-in to NSString to compare these, so you would have to download [confusables.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/security/latest/confusables.txt) and do character-by-character mapping yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty difficult to explain in short. There is much more hidden under the `NSString` and Unicode than one might think. Some (the same visually looking) characters can have more than one representation.

I recommend reading these two great articles at [objc.io](http://objc.io), which exactly explain your issue in deep:

- [NSString and Unicode](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/unicode.html)
- [Working with Strings](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/working-with-strings.html)